# apache2 more then one website per domain

Tags: apache, azure

I got a viritual machine at azure and are trying make it possible to have more then one website on it. But i cant figure out how. I always just get sent to the /var/www/rajohan.no/www index.html. When i type rajohan.no i want the /var/www/rajohan.no/www index.html to show. When i type rajohan.no/test/ i want the /var/www/test.no/www to show. This is my conf files

```
rajohan.no.conf

<Virtual *:80>
   ServerName rajohan.no
   ServerAdmin mail@rajohan.no
   DocumentRoot /var/www/rajohan.no/www
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


test.no.conf

<Virtual *:80>
   ServerName rajohan.no/test/
   ServerAdmin test@test.no
   DocumentRoot /var/www/test.no/www
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test.no.conf

<Virtual *:80>
   ServerName rajohan.no/test/
   ServerAdmin test@test.no
```

We **can't** set servername to `rajohan.no/test/`. We can set multiple domain names to achieve your goal, conf like this:

```
example.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

test.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you just want to use one domain name to access two files, maybe you can move that file `/var/www/test.no/www` to `/var/www/rajohan.no/www`.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)